# Can I run my iPhone unit tests programmatically?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, sentestingkit, kif-framework

Our iPhone app uses the built-in SenTestingKit for unit tests, and KIF for functional tests.  We're using Zapp for CI, which runs the functional tests but not the unit tests.  As a stopgap, I'd like to add a functional test scenario which runs the unit tests.  Is there a way to run SenTestingKit unit tests programmatically?  i.e. not via a script, but from within the application?

Comment: I don't think there is. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new scheme which runs all the tests for your project, and use a script to run all the unit tests ?

For example, if the name of your project is `simon`, the scheme for your test target will be `simonTests`

Run the script on command line

```
xcodebuild .../your_.proj_file_path/ -scheme "simonTests" -sdk iphonesimulator5.0 -configuration "Debug" clean build
```

This build would essentially run unit tests for you.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to run the unit tests from Zapp as part of a KIF test step, so I need to do it programmatically (i.e. from within the app) rather than via a script.

Comment: @Simon You do have a KIF target right ? Can't you set the options for Unit Testing in the schematic ?

Comment: I do, but I'm not trying to run unit tests from a script, I'm trying to run them from within a KIF test scenario.  I want to call some function like STKRunUnitTests() and have them run.